# Why is this complex vector bundle not trivial?

Tags: vector-bundles

Consider the complex line bundle over $S^1$:
$$
E = \left\{(\alpha,z\begin{pmatrix}1\\e^{i\theta_\alpha}\end{pmatrix}): \alpha\in \mathbb{R}/{2\pi}\mathbb{Z}, \rho_\alpha e^{i\theta_\alpha}=a+be^{i\alpha}, z\in\mathbb{C} \right\}\subset \mathbb{R}/{2\pi}\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{C}^2
$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. There are two rather different cases for the behavior of $\theta_\alpha$: $a<b$ and $a>b$.

This bundle is used to compute some invariant in physics. It appears to be trivial for $a>b$ and not trivial for $a<b$. I do not understand why this is the case as
$$
(\alpha,z\begin{pmatrix}1\\e^{i\theta_\alpha}\end{pmatrix}) \mapsto (\alpha,z)
$$
seems a decent global trivialization.

Comment: What is $\rho_{\alpha}$? Every complex line bundle over $S^1$ is trivial, so the values of $a$ and $b$ should be irrelevant.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese $\rho_\alpha$ is just $\vert a+be^{i\alpha}\vert$. Could you provide a reference for the fact that every complex line bundle over $S^1$ is trivial?

Comment: Two different explanations can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/327881/21564).